# jquery video html5 multiple video tacking

Tags: jquery, html, html5-video

I am attempting to get the current video source from a page that has multiple videos, they are separated by id's.

example would be as follows

```
<video id="videoOne"
controls src="videoOne.mp4"
</video>

<video id="videoTwo"
controls src="videoTwo.mp4"
</video>
```

I am able to play track which events are firing by changing the 0 to 1 to reference the appropriate video I just need to be able to do it via jquery but am unsure exactly how to accomplish this

> var current_source = $('video')[0].currentSrc;

in the following jquery

```
var PodcastAnalytics = PodcastAnalytics || {};

// Wait for the video element to be parsed before attempting this.
$(document).ready(function(){

  // Wait until the video metadata has been loaded before we try to determine the current video source.
  $('video').on('loadedmetadata', function(){

    // Simple function to chop off the file extension for the current source of the video. 
    PodcastAnalytics.audio_url = (function(){
      var current_source = $('video')[0].currentSrc;
      return current_source.slice(0, -4);
    }());
    // function that sends the actual tracking beacon
    PodcastAnalytics.gaq_track = function(action) {
      // All events will be in the Video category
      var tracking_params = ['podcast','audio']
      // append the event action after the event method and the event category    
      tracking_params.push(action);
      // append the video url as the event label
      tracking_params.push(PodcastAnalytics.audio_url);

      // Replace this console.log with something like this if you are using Google Analytics:
      // _gaq.push(tracking_params);
      console.log(tracking_params);
    }

    $('video').on('play', function(){
      PodcastAnalytics.gaq_track('Play');
    });

    $('video').on('pause', function(){
      PodcastAnalytics.gaq_track('Pause');
    });

    $('video').on('seeked', function(){
      PodcastAnalytics.gaq_track('Seeked');
    });

    $('video').on('ended', function(){
      PodcastAnalytics.gaq_track('Ended');
    });

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following jquery to get the correct `<video id=""/>` but would still like to know if it's possible and how to go about getting the `currentSrc from e.target.id`

```
$(document).ready(function($){

    $('video').on('loadedmetadata', function() {

            tracking = function(action,id, source) {

                var items = ['podcast','audio',action,id, source];

                console.log(items);
            };
        });

    $('video').off('play').on('play', function(e) {
            var idx = $(this).index();
            var currentSource = $('video')[idx].currentSrc;
            tracking('Play', e.target.id, currentSource);
        });

    $('video').off('pause').on('pause', function(e) {
        tracking('Pause', e.target.id);
    });

    $('video').off('seeked').on('seeked', function(e) {
        tracking('Seeked', e.target.id);
    });

    $('video').off('ended').on('ended', function(e) {
        tracking('Ended', e.target.id);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be way off, and if I am, please let me know and I'll delete my answer.
But here's what I would *try*:

1. inside the outer bind event, grab a reference to the video object.
2. use that to find your current_src
3. continue using it to perform the additional event bindings.

Just a thought.

```
var PodcastAnalytics = PodcastAnalytics || {};

// Wait for the video element to be parsed before attempting this.
$(document).ready(function(){

  // Wait until the video metadata has been loaded before we try to determine the current video source.
  $('video').on('loadedmetadata', function(){
    // should 'this' refer to the video object?
    var $video = $(this); 

    // Simple function to chop off the file extension for the current source of the video. 
    PodcastAnalytics.audio_url = (function(){
      var current_source = $video.attr('currentSrc');
      // var current_source = $('video')[0].currentSrc;
      return current_source.slice(0, -4);
    }());
    // function that sends the actual tracking beacon
    PodcastAnalytics.gaq_track = function(action) {
      // All events will be in the Video category
      var tracking_params = ['podcast','audio']
      // append the event action after the event method and the event category    
      tracking_params.push(action);
      // append the video url as the event label
      tracking_params.push(PodcastAnalytics.audio_url);

      // Replace this console.log with something like this if you are using Google Analytics:
      // _gaq.push(tracking_params);
      console.log(tracking_params);
    }

    $video.on('play', function(){
      PodcastAnalytics.gaq_track('Play');
    });

    $video.on('pause', function(){
      PodcastAnalytics.gaq_track('Pause');
    });

    $video.on('seeked', function(){
      PodcastAnalytics.gaq_track('Seeked');
    });

    $video.on('ended', function(){
      PodcastAnalytics.gaq_track('Ended');
    });

  });

});
```

Comment: thanks for the advice I did update my original post, with new jquery which is now tracking the correct <video id='' />

Comment: you should leave the original as it was, and submit your corrected code as an separate answer and then accept it as the correct answer.  that leaves a  good trail for others to follow.